# How to extract IP numbers from a text file?

Tags: shell-script

How could I extract just IP numbers from a file formatted like what
follows?

```
test-Zookeeper2-Z1-solr1006 10.15.5.226
10.15.6.103 test-Zookeeper2-Z2-solr1006
10.15.5.92 test-Zookeeper3-Z1-solr1006
10.15.6.217 test-Zookeeper1-Z2-solr1006
10.15.6.83 test-Zookeeper3-Z2-solr1006
test-Zookeeper-Z1-solr1006 10.15.7.106
```

Answer (score 16):

Perl has a tried-and-true module for common regular expressions, including IPv4 addresses:

```
$ perl -MRegexp::Common=net -lane 'print for grep {/^$RE{net}{IPv4}$/} @F' file
10.15.5.226
10.15.6.103
10.15.5.92
10.15.6.217
10.15.6.83
10.15.7.106
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sample data:

```
grep -o '\b[0-9.]\+\b'
```

or

```
grep -o '[0-9.]\{7,\}'
```

Comment: or `grep -o '\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}'`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your example input is in a file named `test.in`:

```
sed 's/.*\([1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/' test.in
```

You could spend a lot of time getting everything "just right", like removing duplicates and so on, but this gets you started.

Comment: `sed -n "s/.*\(\([1-9][0-9]*\.\)\{3\}[1-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/p" test.in | sort -Vu`. Regrouped regex, skip non matching lines if any, sort and uniquify.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` way:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^[0-9.]{7,15}$/){print $i}}}' file
10.15.5.226
10.15.6.103
10.15.5.92
10.15.6.217
10.15.6.83
10.15.7.106
```

And another `perl` way:

```
$ perl -lne '/\b[0-9.]{7,15}\b/ && print $&' file
10.15.5.226
10.15.6.103
10.15.5.92
10.15.6.217
10.15.6.83
10.15.7.106
```